# CASE STATEMENT/FUNCTION

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case, where-clause

I need help with a `CASE` statement in Oracle v11. My company uses TRAX Maintenance as its software and the build in "build your own report" uses QuickPrint. I'm trying to do a small `CASE` statement/function but get nothing but error messages. Can anybody help?? Below is the full code (very simple) and the results will return 1 column which is the results.

```
SELECT "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."EO" AS "EO",
       "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."EO_DESCRIPTION" AS "EO_DESCRIPTION",
       CASE,
       WHEN "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_HOURS"=0
   AND "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_CYCLES"=0 THEN "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_DAYS",
       WHEN "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_HOURS"=0
   AND "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_DAYS"=0 THEN "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_CYCLES",
       ELSE "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_HOURS",
       END
  FROM ENGINEERING_ORDER
```

Errors I get is:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
>
> ORA-00936: Missing expression

and others depending on the other ways you can do `CASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the commas (`,`) between `case` and `end`, they shouldn't be there:

```
SELECT "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."EO" AS "EO",
       "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."EO_DESCRIPTION" AS "EO_DESCRIPTION",
       CASE
         WHEN "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_HOURS"=0
          AND "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_CYCLES"=0
         THEN "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_DAYS"
         WHEN "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_HOURS"=0
          AND "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_DAYS"=0 
         THEN "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_CYCLES"
         ELSE "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_HOURS"
       END
  FROM ENGINEERING_ORDER
```

Comment: I removed the '(,)' from 'CASE' & 'End' and still get the same error message

Comment: Did you try my answer, or did you try to remove the commas manually?  Because there is more than one to remove. I had to remove 4.  Just try running my answer directly.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Originally I just did the one after CASE and the one before END. After I removed the rest it worked AWESOME!!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU

Comment: Now I have one more - I need to have it put either "days", "Hrs" or "cyc" for the "THEN" part - see below

Comment: I have one more - I need to have it put the words "days", "Hrs" or "cyc" for the "THEN" part - see below    'CASE
       WHEN "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_AC_HOURS"=0 AND "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_AC_CYCLES"=0 THEN "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_AC_DAYS" AS "DAYS" END '  I get the following:     "missing keyword"   when I try this way:   'CASE
       WHEN "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_AC_HOURS"=0 AND "ENGINEERING_ORDER"."SCHEDULE_AC_CYCLES"=0 THEN "DAYS" END' I get "DAYS": invalid identifier

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes: `'DAYS'`.  Single quotes are used for string literals.  Double quotes are used for identifiers.